# Bash: Filtering records in a file based on multi column delimiter

Tags: bash, awk

Need help in Bash to filter records based on a multicolumn delimiter.
Delimiter is |^^|

Sample record

```
xyz@ATT.NET|^^|xyz|^^|307
```

Awk runs file when used with single character delimiter but not with multi character.

```
awk -F"|^^|" "NF !=3  {print}" file.txt
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that every character in your delimiter is a regexp metacharacter so you need to escape them when appropriate so awk knows you want them treated literally. This might be overkill:

```
awk -F'\\|\\^\\^\\|' 'NF!=3' file.txt
```

but I can't test it since you only provided one line of input, not the selection of lines some of which do/don't match that'd be required to test the script.

Comment: can we use `\\` to escape anchor?

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure you click on the check mark next to whichever answer you accept once enough time has passed that you're comfortable you're not going to get a "better" answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F "<regex>" ...
```

It is not a multicolumn delimiter,  is is a regular expression

simple regex, 
such as match this single char are what you get use to, 
but not all there is.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to escape all the regex characters as [@Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) answered.

Alternatively,
you can replace all `|^^|` with a single character which never shows in your file content, here let's say a comma

```
sed 's/|^^|/,/g' file.txt
xyz@ATT.NET,xyz,307
```

The command would be

`sed 's/|^^|/,/g' file.txt | awk -F, 'NF != 3'`